# Can two or more separate Numbers spreadsheets (not sheets) interact?

Tags: macos, numbers, automation

I have two separate spreadsheets.

- On one, I have the accounting and calculations for my business.
- On the other, I have what I call Daily compensation sheets.

My employees use these compensation sheets to list their revenue for the week. I then take that information and enter it into my business sheet and it calculates weekly, monthly, quarterly, and yearly data. More importantly to my employees, it calculates what their checks will be. I want to set it up where they can enter their numbers into their individual compensation sheets and that information automatically fills my business sheet. I don't want them to be able to gain access to or view my business sheet; so I need the spreadsheets to remain separate.

Is this sort of cross document linking viable or could it be automated on macOS?